# Angularjs condition for Saving and Updating

Tags: angularjs

I have one div with two fields.For first time if no records are there i want to save it .Right now it is happening.After that i am displaying the data.But if i change the data and update it is adding new row with updated data instead of updating same row.

Here is my html

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12"
    <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="even" data-ng-repeat="infraitem in
    allInfraitemsByType">
    <td><strong>{{infraitem.name}}</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text"  
    name="requiredseat" data-ng-model="infraitem.requiredseat"></td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="available" data-ng- 
    model="infraitem.available"></td>
    <td class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn GreenBtn" 
    data-ng-click="saveInfrastructureDetails(infraitem)"><span 
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Save</button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </div>
```

Here is the controller.js

```
    $scope.saveInfrastructureDetails = function(infraitem){
    AdminCollegeService.saveInfrastructureDetails(infraitem).then
    (function(response)
    {
    if(response.data=="success")
    {
        $scope.infraitem = {};
        $scope.successmessageinfra="Infra Structure Details Saved";
    });
    }
```

Can anyone tell how to update same row if data is already present instead of adding new record.

Comment: How are you getting the value for allInfraitemsByType?

Comment: You're missing a > on the end of the opening div

Comment: From controller.js i am writing method.The response returned i am doing ng-repeat for allInfraitemsByType

Answer (score 0):

- make sure `$scope.saveInfrastructureDetails` function is hitting
- make sure  `$scope.saveInfrastructureDetails` is update the data to database or insert the data.

***But the main think is***

> - make sure are you using `form` tag for inserting records, if yes then change your update button type **`type="submit"` to `type="button"`**

This below sample like a key. I am saving and updating data with a array.

### EDIT

```js
angular.module("test",[]).controller("testCont", function($scope)
{
$scope.testArray =[{id:1,name:"Me"},{id:0,name:''}];
$scope.Save=function(data)
{
if(data.id == 0)
{
data.id=2;//instert code
}
else
{
return false;// you can call your update code
}
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller='testCont'>
 <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="testobject in testArray">
                <td>Name {{testobject.id}}</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="testobject.name" />
                </td>
                <td><input value="save" type="button" ng-click="Save(testobject)" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Here i am using only one div element.Is it possible to check condition so that if data is not there i can execute save otherwise update method

Comment: Am not understand what you mean? `The data is not there`. What you mean. how to insert you without data?

Comment: For first time fields will be empty.So if i enter some data and save then it will insert into database.Now if i change the value to some other then it should update same row instead of adding another row

Comment: @SachinHR . I just give a key answer to understand you what logic you need.